# Show that $f(z)=\alpha$ has exactly $n$-distinct roots except for finitely many $\alpha \in \mathbb C$.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

> Let $f(z)$ be a complex polynomial then show that except for finitely many $\alpha \in \mathbb C$ the equation $f(z)=\alpha$ has $n$-distinct roots except for finitely many $\alpha \in \mathbb C$, where $n$ is the degree of $f$.

I have tried my level best but I have failed to do it. How can I show that? Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can look at the derivative of $f-\alpha$ and recall a condition on $h$ and $h'$ to check that a root of $h$ is simple.

Comment: That means for any $\alpha \in \mathbb C$ multiple roots of $f(z)=\alpha$ are the roots of $f'(z)=0$. How does it imply the required result?

Comment: What kind of function is $f'(z)$ and so how many roots does it have?

Comment: No, they're not the roots of $f'$, but they're included in them. And what can you say about the number of roots of a non zero polynomial?

Answer (score 1):

$z$ is a multiple root is equivalent to $P(z)-\alpha=0$ and $P'(z)=0$, there are finitely many $z$ such that $P'(z)=0$, $c_1,...,c_p$, which are the potential multiple roots of $P(z)-\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use A.Rod's hint in the the comments. So that we have something useful to say about the roots of $f'(z)=0$, use induction on $n$.